# Managing Registry With PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, permissions, registry

I'm creating a reg key in HKCU which I want to audit with other scripts. I want to ensure that all other users (to include other admins) are unable to edit this key.

I'm looking to write a quick blerb that wipes the current permissions or sets them all to Deny and then adds full control to my user. I believe I have to break Inheriting too, which I'm not sure how to do. If possible I'd like to do all of this through PowerShell, although I'm curious how that would work with GPO as well.  This is what I have so far.

```
# Set Validation Key
Push-Location
Set-Location HKCU:
Test-Path .\System\Security
New-Item -Path .\System -Name Security
Set-Item -Path HKCU:\System\Security -Value "Yes"
Rename-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\System\Security -Name '(Default)' -NewName 'Validated'
Pop-Location 

# Manage Key Permissions
$Acl = Get-Acl "HKCU:\System\Security"
$Acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll()
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule('username', 'fullcontrol', 'allow')
$Acl.SetAccessrule($Ar)
```

Comment: "*I want to ensure that all other users (to include other admins) are unable to edit this key.*" - admins will always be able to take ownership and then edit it.

Comment: _"or sets them all to Deny[...]"_ You'll make yourself very unhappy... (But like @TessellatingHeckler said, admins can take ownership). Would say it won't work...